# When sticky element is removed in Safari, all content shifts

Tags: css, safari, sticky

I need to remove sticky element at some point in Safari, so I'm adding `display: none;`. It happens after user scrolled to the middle of the page. In Chrome it works fine, but in Safari whole page content shifts.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Scroll down with sticky element and apply `display: none` (click 'Hide header')
2. You'll see layout shift.

I tested it on both mac and mobile Safari.

It happens only in Safari. Why is it happening and is there a way to fix it?

```js
const hideHeader = () => {
const header = document.getElementById("sticky_header");
header.style.display = 'none';
}

const showHeader = () => {
const header = document.getElementById("sticky_header");
header.style.display = 'flex';
}
```

```css
main{
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
border: 1px solid grey;
}

header{
top:0;
position: sticky;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
background: #ebf1f5;
height: 50px;
box-shadow: 0 0 25px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

header button{
height: 30px;
background: #7dcbff;
border-radius: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
border: none;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}

section{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}

section button{
height: 30px;
background: #ff7de5;
border-radius: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
border: none;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
<header id='sticky_header'>
<p>Sticky header</p>
<button onclick="hideHeader()">Hide header</button>
</header>
<section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p> <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p> <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
<button onclick="showHeader()">Show header</button>
</section>
</main>
```